# React-native: Calculation returns NaN when Input has empty text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm building a fee calculator with React-Native, and I have multiple input fields that variables for my calculation are set with.

Everything works well when the input fields have correct values however if the user hits backspace on what they have previously input and then try to calculate profit with an empty field the total shows up as NaN.

Here is my code so far:

```
this.state = {
       text: '',
       soldPrice: 0,
       shippingCost: 0,
       shippingCharge: 0,
       itemCost: 0,
       profit: 0,
       paypalFee: 0.30,
       paypalFeePercentage: 0.029,
       ebayFee: 0.1
     };
  }

  calculateProfit = () => {
    const { soldPrice, shippingCost, shippingCharge, itemCost,
      paypalFee, ebayFee, paypalFeePercentage
     } = this.state;


     let sp = parseFloat(soldPrice);
     const sc = parseFloat(shippingCost);
     const sCharge = parseFloat(shippingCharge);
     const ic = parseFloat(itemCost);
     const pf = parseFloat(paypalFee);
     const ef = parseFloat(ebayFee);
     const pfp = parseFloat(paypalFeePercentage);

// sp = soldPrice, sc = shippingCost,
// sCharge = shippingCharge, ic = itemCost,
// pf = paypalFee, ef = ebayFee, pfp = paypalFeePercentage, c = calculation


     const calculation = sp - sp * pfp -
     pf
     - sp * ef - sc
     - ic;

     sp += sCharge;

     if (!this.state.itemCost) {
       this.setState({ itemCost: 0 });
     }

     let i;
// if profit is more than 10 than the profit will be displayed as 00.00
// otherwise it will be displayed as 0.00
     if (calculation > 1000) {
       i = 6;
     } else if (calculation > 100) {
       i = 5;
     } else if (calculation > 10) {
       i = 4;
     }
     const roundedNumber = calculation.toPrecision(i);
    this.setState({
      profit: roundedNumber
    });
  }

 render() {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>

     <View style={styles.header}>
     <Text style={styles.headerText}>Efees</Text>
     </View>

     <View style={styles.blocks}>

     <View style={styles.inputs}>
     <Text style={styles.inputText}>Sold Price</Text>

     <TextInput
         underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
         style={styles.TextInputStyle}
         placeholder='0.00'
         keyboardType={'numeric'}
         value={this.state.soldPrice}
         onChangeText={(soldPrice) => this.setState({ soldPrice })}
     />

     </View>

     <View style={styles.inputs}>
     <Text style={styles.inputText}>Shipping Charge</Text>

     <TextInput
         underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
         style={styles.TextInputStyle}
         placeholder='0.00'
         keyboardType={'numeric'}
         value={this.state.shippingCharge}
         onChangeText={(shippingCharge) => this.setState({ shippingCharge })}
     />

     </View>

     <View style={styles.inputs}>
     <Text style={styles.inputText}>Shipping Cost</Text>

     <TextInput
         underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
         style={styles.TextInputStyle}
         placeholder='0.00'
         keyboardType={'numeric'}
         value={this.state.shippingCost}
         onChangeText={(shippingCost) => this.setState({ shippingCost })}
     />

     </View>

     <View style={styles.inputs}>
     <Text style={styles.inputText}>Item Cost</Text>

     <TextInput
         underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
         style={styles.TextInputStyle}
         placeholder='0.00'
         keyboardType={'numeric'}
         value={this.state.itemCost}
         onChangeText={(itemCost) => this.setState({ itemCost })}
     />

     </View>

     <View style={styles.inputs}>



            </View>

     </View>

     <TouchableOpacity
     style={styles.calcButton}
     onPress={this.calculateProfit}
     >
        <Text style={styles.calcText}>Calculate </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <Text>{`Profit: $${this.state.profit}`}</Text>


      </View>
 );
 }
}
```

Comment: If you try to convert an empty string to a number, the result is NaN (not a number). If you meant empty fields to be zero, you have to put that into your program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is caused by [`parseFloat()` returning `Number.NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat#Return_value) when attempting to parse an empty string:

```js
/* Parse a valid value */
console.log( parseFloat('1.2') , '===', 1.2 );

/* Parse an empty string yields NaN */
console.log( parseFloat('') , '===', Number.NaN );
```

When a `Number.NaN` is introduced into the arithmetic of your subsequent calculation by one or more variables, the value of `calculation` will be `Number.NaN`:

```js
const sp = 1,
      pfp = 1,
      ef = 1,
      pf = 1,
      sc = 1,
      ic = Number.NaN;

const calculation = sp - sp * pfp - pf - sp * ef - sc - ic;

console.log(calculation);
```

There are many ways to resolve this issue - a simple method that requires minimal change with your current code would be as follows:

```
calculateProfit = () => {
  const {
    soldPrice,
    shippingCost,
    shippingCharge,
    itemCost,
    paypalFee,
    ebayFee,
    paypalFeePercentage
  } = this.state;

  /* 
  Define helper function that recovers a 0 as a default value
  if "non-a-number" results from parseFloat
  */
  const safeParseFloat = (str) => {

    const value = Number.parseFloat(str);

    return Number.isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;    
  }

  /*
  Use locally defined helper to safely parse strings while also
  accounting form empty string mapping to 0
  */
  let sp = safeParseFloat(soldPrice);
  const sc = safeParseFloat(shippingCost);
  const sCharge = safeParseFloat(shippingCharge);
  const ic = safeParseFloat(itemCost);
  const pf = safeParseFloat(paypalFee);
  const ef = safeParseFloat(ebayFee);
  const pfp = safeParseFloat(paypalFeePercentage);

  const calculation = sp - sp * pfp - pf - sp * ef - sc - ic;

  sp += sCharge;

  if (!this.state.itemCost) {
    this.setState({
      itemCost: 0
    });
  }

  let i;
  // if profit is more than 10 than the profit will be displayed as 00.00
  // otherwise it will be displayed as 0.00
  if (calculation > 1000) {
    i = 6;
  } else if (calculation > 100) {
    i = 5;
  } else if (calculation > 10) {
    i = 4;
  }
  const roundedNumber = calculation.toPrecision(i);

  this.setState({
    profit: roundedNumber
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much you don't even understand how frustrating it was for me i just couldn't see what was breaking it i'm a beginner and its so amazingly helpful to have people like you and a community like this to help me through this often daunting task of creating your first app

Comment: Worked! you pinpointed what was wrong and gave a simple solution

Comment: @prog you're welcome - glad I could help! All the best with your project and learning :)

Comment: Thanks, Prog & @Dacre Denny this helped me also